# ADAL token Persist in Database

Tags: .net, sql-server, adal

I am using ADAL(Azure Directory authentication Library) to talk to Office 365 API. I understand I need to persist byte array from `Serialize()`. 
In Memory everything works fine.

I am trying to persist that in to `varchar` in SQL server which in .net c# code is essentially string.

How can I persist byte array in to the DB and read it back. I don't know what encoding is used to get the byte array. I have tried ASCII and of course it does not work.
Any experts out there?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the bytes into `varchar` field, you need to encoder it first. For example, you can encode the bytes into string using base64 encoding.

However it is not necessary to encode the bytes, we can store it to the SQL using the `varbinary` field directly. Here is a piece of code using the database to store the token from this [code sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-ASPNETMVC-Start.git):

```
public class ADALTokenCache : TokenCache
{
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        string User;
        UserTokenCache Cache;

        // constructor
        public ADALTokenCache(string user)
        {
            // associate the cache to the current user of the web app
            User = user;
            this.AfterAccess = AfterAccessNotification;
            this.BeforeAccess = BeforeAccessNotification;
            this.BeforeWrite = BeforeWriteNotification;

            // look up the entry in the DB
            Cache = db.UserTokenCacheList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.webUserUniqueId == User);
            // place the entry in memory
            this.Deserialize((Cache == null) ? null : Cache.cacheBits);
        }

        // clean up the DB
        public override void Clear()
        {
            base.Clear();
            foreach (var cacheEntry in db.UserTokenCacheList)
                db.UserTokenCacheList.Remove(cacheEntry);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        // Notification raised before ADAL accesses the cache.
        // This is your chance to update the in-memory copy from the DB, if the in-memory version is stale
        void BeforeAccessNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
        {
            if (Cache == null)
            {
                // first time access
                Cache = db.UserTokenCacheList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.webUserUniqueId == User);
            }
            else
            {   // retrieve last write from the DB
                var status = from e in db.UserTokenCacheList
                             where (e.webUserUniqueId == User)
                             select new
                             {
                                 LastWrite = e.LastWrite
                             };
                // if the in-memory copy is older than the persistent copy
                if (status.First().LastWrite > Cache.LastWrite)
                //// read from from storage, update in-memory copy
                {
                    Cache = db.UserTokenCacheList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.webUserUniqueId == User);
                }
            }
            this.Deserialize((Cache == null) ? null : Cache.cacheBits);
        }

        // Notification raised after ADAL accessed the cache.
        // If the HasStateChanged flag is set, ADAL changed the content of the cache
        void AfterAccessNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
        {
            // if state changed
            if (this.HasStateChanged)
            {
                Cache = new UserTokenCache
                {
                    webUserUniqueId = User,
                    cacheBits = this.Serialize(),
                    LastWrite = DateTime.Now
                };
                //// update the DB and the lastwrite                
                db.Entry(Cache).State = Cache.UserTokenCacheId == 0 ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                this.HasStateChanged = false;
            }
        }

        void BeforeWriteNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
        {
            // if you want to ensure that no concurrent write take place, use this notification to place a lock on the entry
        }
    }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserTokenCache> UserTokenCacheList { get; set; }
}

public class UserTokenCache
{
    [Key]
    public int UserTokenCacheId { get; set; }
    public string webUserUniqueId { get; set; }
    public byte[] cacheBits { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastWrite { get; set; }
}
```